# How can a .NET Core Worker Service be published to ensure it is not in Production mode (DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT)?

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, production-environment

I have a .NET Core Worker Service with some code that is different between Development/Staging and Production. I understand how to [set **DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT** on the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for Development or Staging.

Locally in my IDE, the Worker Service runs as Development or Staging, because **DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT** is set to *Development* (or *Staging*) in *launchSettings.json*. But, when publishing to a server, this setting is ignored.

What I want to prevent, is in the future, if a new server is spun up and used for our Worker Services, that the code is not run in Production mode (which is the default, if the environment variable **DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT** is not present). Right now, the only way to prevent it is by setting the Environment Variable, and I do not want to count on the person spinning up the new server to have to set this variable. Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: You can distribute a helper script with the executable. `run.bat` / `run.sh` sets the environment variable then executes the worker and passes all parameters to it.

Answer (score 2):

To do this change it is important to know exactly what type of environment you are deploying to, whether your application is Dockerized/Containerized or you are deploying directly on a server.
Most of these Configurations for making an application work in multiple environments most require extra configuration within your build pipeline to make this happen automatically.

if you application is runs in a docker container you might also want to make the following changes to your Dockerfile to be able to update the application running in the container with the right env variables

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-buster-slim AS base
ARG DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
CMD echo $DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=$DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Worker/Worker.csproj", "Worker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Worker/Worker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Worker"
RUN dotnet build "Worker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Worker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Worker.dll"]
```

Consider the section below which takes the env variable injected from the pipeline confuration and uses it to set the application environment

```
ARG DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
CMD echo $DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=$DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
```

Additional information of injecting the environmental variable can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can always hardcode the environment variable inside your code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // override env variable before building the host
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");

        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        var env = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>();
        Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName); // outputs "Development"

        host.Run();
    }

    // ...
}
```